# shell script execution successful but output has errors, how to determine error and exit main script?

Tags: shell, error-handling

I have a main script. Inside it I call other three shell scripts, A,B and C. All were successful. Exit codes are all equal to zero. However, when I looked into the output file of the first script which is A, it contains an error message. Now I want to exit the main script and not to continue running the other scripts after the script that has output error. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if some command in your first bash script results in an error, the script as a whole may complete with exit code 0.

You can check the exit code of any individual command in your script by using the `$?` variable. This variable stores the exit code of the previous command. This will allow you to check for errors within the script.

Comment: My first script still has an exit code of 0 though it produces an error. Here is what my script does. I have a shell script that writes an sql script and dumps its result to a csv file. Though the output has errors the exit code of the script is still 0 since it ran. Is there a way I could capture error on the output file?

Comment: @smflores07 I don't know exactly what you mean by "capture the error", but whatever you choose to do with the error you can detect it by checking `$?` within your script after any error prone commands. If the previous line of code produced an error then `$?` will be something other than zero. This is how I've been taught to catch errors in bash. I don't understand why this wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: Oh I understand the confusion! You would check `$?` **within your first script** not in the other ones. You have to detect the error immediately after the failed line of code or else there will be no easily accessible record of it.

Comment: Could you please look my subscript below?                                             #!/bin/bash
FILE=/data/temp/Jollibee/TableauExtract/Infile/MainJobs/LastExtractionDate.csv
#echo "Start time:"
#date;
while IFS=',' read lastdate_suc
do
echo "\vdelim |
\trim
SELECT * from factsales \g" > /data/temp/Jollibee/TableauExtract/Infile/MainJobs/test/ExtractStoreInc.sql
/opt/Actian/Vectorwise/ingres/bin/sql -S jfcdw_Jollibee_is < /data/temp/Jollibee/TableauExtract/Infile/MainJobs/test/ExtractStoreInc.sql > /data/temp/Jollibee/TableauExtract/Infile/MainJobs/test/StoreKey_All.csv

Comment: I want to know if this has error, if it has the main script will exit but if not process will continue to execute the next subscript.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to append `|| exit 1` to the statement which is throwing the error. That will cause the script to exit if the exit code of the command is `1` (i.e. an error).
So assuming you had a command `sqlscript` and you wanted the entire script to exit if `sqlscript` exited with a non-zero exit code you would do

```
sqlscript || exit 1
```

As a point of trivia, the `1` in `exit 1` is not needed. A plain `exit` command would also exit with the exit status of the last executed command.
Which would be `false` (code=1) if the `sqlscript` command fails.  If the `sqlscript` command succeeds, the exit code is the exit code of `sqlscript`. In that case, the `||` does not trigger and the `exit` command is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a main script. Inside it I call other three shell scripts, A,B
>   and C. All were successful. Exit codes are all equal to zero. However,
>   when I looked into the output file of the first script which is A, it
>   contains an error message. Now I want to exit the main script and not
>   to continue running the other scripts after the script that has output
>   error.

Since script A doesn't return an error exit code, you have to inspect its output. This is quite easy with `grep` provided that you have a search string which clearly identifies an error message, e. g.:

```
# this echo command simulates script A - it outputs "error" and exits with 0:
echo "contains an error message" >StoreKey_All.csv  # assumed this output file
grep error StoreKey_All.csv && exit 1               # exit if output has error
# continue with scripts B and C
echo B
```